# Amazon EMR - Java SDK - how to get job results

Tags: java, emr, amazon-emr

I'm using Amazon EMR service to manage some big-data hive tables.
I want to know the number of items in a table from my code.
Currently I'm running a query, something like:

```
select count(*) from myTable;
```

Saving the results into a file on S3 from the EMR and then read this file from the code from S3 to get the results.

Is there a direct way to get the output of a query using the Java SDK without the need to go through S3?

Comment: This is not from the Java SDK, but have you looked at [Apache Zeppelin](https://zeppelin.incubator.apache.org/)?  It is geared at ad-hoc analysis and has a hive interpreter.  I believe it has been supported on EMR since emr-4.1.0+.

Comment: @Greg -Thanks, that looks good. But we already hardly invested in the EMR-HIVE-JAVA solution in the company and it looks like an extreme change now for such a small required feature.

Comment: I would recommend interfacing with Hive using JDBC, then you can pick up the results programmatically. See https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveServer2+Clients

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it by integrating with `org.apache.hive:hive-jdbc`.

Thanks to @ChristopherB advice.